# Printf display only one word

Tags: c++

I want to display more than one word using printf, Do I should change first parameter in pritnf?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>



int main() {
    
    int value;
    printf("How many:"); scanf("%d", &value);

    char* arr1 = new char[value];

    scanf("%s[^\n]", arr1);

    printf("%s", arr1);

    delete [] arr1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be `"%[^\n]"`, without the `s`.

Comment: Please specify exactly the input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: I tried without `s` but it doesn't work

Comment: You should use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` when reading in text. Or, since you tagged the question as `c++`, stop writing C in a C++ compiler, use proper C++ idioms like `std::string` and `std::cin`/`std::cout` and `std::getline()` , instead of C idioms like `char*` and `printf()` and `scanf()`.

Comment: @HyperRoll10: I tested it and it works with me if I remove the `s`. Are you sure that this is the only change that you made?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes I removed only 's'. I use Visual Studio 2019. When I want to enter '10' to 'value' program displays `══════════²²²²`, it's looks like ASCII for me but I do not know.

Comment: @HyperRoll10: Yes, I was wrong and you were right that it doesn't work, even if you remove the `s`. See my answer for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments section, the following line is wrong:

```
scanf("%s[^\n]", arr1);
```

The `%s` and `%[^\n]` are distinct conversion format specifiers. You seem to be attempting to use a hybrid of both. If you want to read a whole line of input, you should use the second one.

However, even if you fix this line, your program will not work, for the following reason:

The statement

```
scanf("%d", &value);
```

will read a number from standard input, but will only extract the number itself from the input stream. The newline character after the input will not be extracted.

Therefore, when you later call

```
scanf("%[^\n]", arr1);
```

it will extract everything that remained from the previous `scanf` function call up to the newline character. This will result in no characters being extracted if the newline character immediately follows the number (which is normally the case).

Example of program's behavior:

```
How many:20ExtraInput
ExtraInput
```

As you can see, everything after the number up to the newline character is being extracted in the second `scanf` function call (which is then printed). However, this is not what you want. You want to extract everything that comes after the newline character instead.

In order to fix this, you must discard everything up to and including the newline character beforehand. This must be done between the two `scanf` function calls.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    int value;
    int c;

    printf("How many:"); scanf("%d", &value);

    char* arr1 = new char[value];

    //discard remainder of line, including newline character
    do
    {
        c = getchar();

    } while ( c != EOF && c != '\n' );

    scanf("%[^\n]", arr1);

    printf("%s", arr1);

    delete [] arr1;
    return 0;
}
```

The program now has the following behavior:

```
How many:20ExtraInput
This is a test.
This is a test.
```

As you can see, the program now discards `ExtraInput` and it correctly echoes the line `This is a test.`